# MiKTeX 1 vs 0 MacTeX (in using package bigfoot)

Tags: miktex, texlive, mactex, bigfoot

A simpliest testing .tex file (under a preamble used in my book) is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,openbib]{book} 
\usepackage[total={5in, 8in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}

\begin{document}
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing\footnote{Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 Footnote 1 
    } Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
    Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing
\end{document}
```

When compiling it with MiKTeX (+WinEdt or TexStudio), it turns out the pdf as follows, which is correct.
[image]
[image]
However, when compiling it with MacTex (+ TexStudio), it turns out the pdf as follows, in which the footnote appears before its footnote mark.
[image]
[image]

Comment: the difference will not be because of miktex/texlive differences. You will be using different versions of packages or of latex. Add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then the log file will list all packages and their versions at the end of the file. Compare the lists from the two versions.

Comment: You have posted a rather confusing set of full page images, and ask about footnotes but the fonts or encoding seem to be corrupted in the second case. For example "Kedrup's" in the last of the first set becomes "kedrup¡¯s"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did sudo tlmgr update --self and Tex Live Utility update. But the problem is still there.

Comment: did you do as I suggested and use \listfiles, also check that the file on the two machines is the same not corrupted during file transfer.

Comment: Also: Is it possible that the two systems are using different fonts? What does the PDF say about the embedded fonts? Is it possible that Windows line endings are being mis-read my Mac, or vice-versa?

Comment: Which encodings are the editors using when opening the files?

Comment: BTW, `WinEdt` is pronounced as "we need it", it's not a shortcut for "Windows Editor". So, it's `WinEdt` but not `WinEdit`.

Comment: The problem origins from encoding. Please kindly check the encoding of the `.tex` file, and the encoding used by your editors.

Comment: @Ch'enMeng Thanks. I am a very beginner to LaTex. May I learn more from you? My TexStudio uses UTF-8 as its default font encoding. But how can I know the encoding of my .tex file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle after checking the files on my mac and my friend's win, the package bigfoot in my MacBook is the latest one and other are almost same.

Comment: utf-8 is the encoding of your source file not a font encoding. first make sure the two systems are using exactly the same package versions, then if they still produce different results it is easier to debug (perhaps you have different fonts installed)

Comment: @Ch'enMeng It is probably not because of the encoding. I use my friend's tex-file which is changed with encoding, but the problem remains.

Comment: @KingChungLo Can you please future minimise your code? Can you replicate the problem without special fonts and xeCJK? More people might be able to help you without them. Packages related to tables and index make are probably unnecessary for the example, are they? Can you post the .log from both compiling with mactex and miktex?

Comment: If that example is really minimal, can't you just manage without one of the aliases or shortcuts? The latter obfuscate your code unnecessarily in any case.

Comment: @cfr  done as request

Comment: @KingChungLo Please have a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Please consider throwing away unnecessary code in your preamble for the MWE. Only the lines needed to reproduce the issue should be left.

Comment: @moewe done as your request.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you could remove the reference to the font that not everyone might have (`Gandhari Unicode`) this would be a brilliant MWE. Unfortunately, I can't vote to re-open your question again, but hopefully people will see the new MWE and vote to re-open when the question gets into the queue.

Comment: BTW: You could make your MWE even shorter if remove `\frontmatter` and friends, as well as a few of the unneeded footnote definitions.

Comment: Just an observation: On my fully updated MikTeX system I get the second output, i.e. the one where the footnote marker in the text appears after the footnote on the page. So it might indeed just be a version issue.

Comment: @moewe Do you mean that the problem appears in your latest version of MiKTeX as well? If that is the case, we can then blame the package of bigfoot.

Comment: Yes. I can even reproduce the issue with a smaller preamble: https://gist.github.com/moewew/0136417d9a59b7ebb217e06b7d655651 If that does it for you, you might want to consider making your example even more minimal. You might also want to change the title to make it clearer what it is about and clean up the sports metaphor.

Comment: @moewe I have replaced the MWE with the one you offer. Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure that it indeed reproduces the problem on your MacTeX, but not in your MikTeX. We don't want an example that is too minimal.

Comment: @moewe Yes, the problem remains only on my MacTeX. On MiKTeX (my version installed from CTeX package), it is fine.

Comment: I don’t know why this has been reopened. The new format of the example doesn’t definitely produce the shown images. Moreover, the requested information about versions of the used packages is still missing.